# how to read data from Shield UI grid datasource after applying savechanges method?

Tags: python, django, shieldui

I am using Shield UI grid for displaying data in html page.I have applied savechanges method on datasource. I want to pass this saved data to excel. How can i read the updated data from the data source using java script.

Answer (score 0):

After programmatically saving the data source, you can call the [exportExcel()](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/exportExcel) method.

And in order to have the data source to be read again on an export, you should set the [exportOptions.excel.readDataSource](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/exportOptions/excel) property to `true`.